# scrapy python typeerror positional argument

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my first scrapy project, and the purpose is to scrape this page “http://books.toscrape.com/”.

The page contains a several link for books.

The idea is to scrape the title of the books.

Here is the code:

```
import scrapy


class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    allowed_domains = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']
    start_urls = ['http://http://books.toscrape.com//']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_books = response.xpath('//article')
        for book in all_books:
            title = book.xpath('.//h3/a/@title').extract()
            print(title)


SpiderSpider().parse()
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:/Users/Sayed/PycharmProjects/books/books/spiders/spider.py", line 17, in <module>
    SpiderSpider().parse()

TypeError: parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that there are two mistakes in your code:

1. You are missing the `__init__` function from your `scrappy.Spider` class
2. You are not supposed to call your spider like that, `SpiderSpider().parse`, as far as I know, the way to do it is to run:

```
$ scrapy crawl [yourSpiderName]
```

For this particular case:

```
$ scrapy crawl spider
```

When doing this, be sure that you are in the same folder path as your `scrapy.cfg` file.

For the first point, the correct way for your spider code is:

```py
import scrapy

class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SpiderSpider,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.allowed_domains = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']
        self.start_urls = ['http://http://books.toscrape.com//']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_books = response.xpath('//article')
        for book in all_books:
            title = book.xpath('.//h3/a/@title').extract()
            print(title)
```

Hope this point you in the right direction. Also, I don't know how did you create this scrapy project, but scrapy already comes with templates for your projects, making easier to develop fast and reliable solutions. To create a project template use:

```
$ scrapy startproject [NameOfYourProject]
```

To generate a new spider do:

```
$ cd [NameOfYourProject]
$ scrapy genspider [yourSpiderName]
```

Please feel free to ask if you have any questions! :D

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following command to execute the script:

`scrapy runspider <script_name>.py`

(after you remove  `SpiderSpider().parse()` line)

Answer (score 0):

You should not call parse() method directly. It is called automatically when Scrapy gets a response.
Instead of that use Command line runner.
Follow this link for help : [Command Line Runner](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html)

Scrapy Project already has a template, Instead of doing like this use that, that will be easy.